# Calculate the standard deviation of grouped data in a Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have user logs that I have taken from a csv and converted into a DataFrame in order to leverage the SparkSQL querying features.  A single user will create numerous entries per hour, and I would like to gather some basic statistical information for each user; really just the count of the user instances, the average, and the standard deviation of numerous columns.  I was able to quickly get the mean and count information by using groupBy($"user") and the aggregator with SparkSQL functions for count and avg:

```
val meanData = selectedData.groupBy($"user").agg(count($"logOn"),
avg($"transaction"), avg($"submit"), avg($"submitsPerHour"), avg($"replies"),
avg($"repliesPerHour"), avg($"duration"))
```

However, I cannot seem to find an equally elegant way to calculate the standard deviation.  So far I can only calculate it by mapping a string, double pair and use StatCounter().stdev utility:

```
val stdevduration = duration.groupByKey().mapValues(value =>
org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter(value).stdev)
```

This returns an RDD however, and I would like to try and keep it all in a DataFrame for further queries to be possible on the returned data.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Spark 1.6+**

You can use `stddev_pop` to compute population standard deviation and `stddev` / `stddev_samp` to compute unbiased sample standard deviation:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{stddev_samp, stddev_pop}

selectedData.groupBy($"user").agg(stddev_pop($"duration"))
```

**Spark 1.5 and below** (*The original answer*):

Not so pretty and biased (same as the value returned from `describe`) but using formula:

[image: wikipedia sdev]

you can do something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sqrt

selectedData
    .groupBy($"user")
    .agg((sqrt(
        avg($"duration" * $"duration") -
        avg($"duration") * avg($"duration")
     )).alias("duration_sd"))
```

You can of course create a function to reduce the clutter:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
def mySd(col: Column): Column = {
    sqrt(avg(col * col) - avg(col) * avg(col))
}

df.groupBy($"user").agg(mySd($"duration").alias("duration_sd"))
```

It is also possible to use Hive UDF:

```
df.registerTempTable("df")
sqlContext.sql("""SELECT user, stddev(duration)
                  FROM df
                  GROUP BY user""")
```

---

Source of the image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation

(minor edit to fix typo)

Comment: Works Perfect!  Thank you very much for the great answer, and for adding in the alias function call.

Comment: super minor typo:  stdev -> stddev

Comment: There are three functions in SparkSQL functions: stddev, stddev_samp, stddev_pop. So is there a need for a custom implementation anymore?

Comment: @M.Rez Exactly like I've mentioned in the edit. As far as I remember in 1.6 it was not possible to use builti-in `stddev*` with window functions (so it could be used there) but it is no longer the problem in 2.x branch.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted code does not compile, as it has a typo (as pointed out by MRez). The snippet below works and is tested.

**For Spark 2.0+** :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val _avg_std = df.groupBy("user").agg(
        avg(col("duration").alias("avg")),
        stddev(col("duration").alias("stdev")),
        stddev_pop(col("duration").alias("stdev_pop")),
        stddev_samp(col("duration").alias("stdev_samp"))
        )
```