# How to find standard deviation in a column in a RDD in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, standard-deviation

I have an `RDD` and I want to find the `standard deviation` in the data that is one of the columns of `RDD`. My current code is:

```
def extract(line):
    # line[11] is the column in which I want to find standard deviation
    return (line[1],line[2],line[5],line[6],line[8],line[10],line[11])

inputfile1 = sc.textFile('file1.csv').zipWithIndex().filter(lambda (line,rownum): rownum>=0).map(lambda (line, rownum): line)


data = (inputfile1
    .map(lambda line: line.split(";"))
    .filter(lambda line: len(line) >1 )
    .map(extract)) # Map to tuples
```

`data` is the `RDD` in which I the last column (column 6) has the values among which I want to find the `standard deviation`. How can I find it?

**UPDATE**: My current code:

```
def extract(line):
    # last column is numeric but in string format
    return ((float(line[-1])))


input = sc.textFile('file1.csv').zipWithIndex().filter(lambda (line,rownum): rownum>=0).map(lambda (line, rownum): line)

Data = (input
    .map(lambda line: line.split(";"))
    .filter(lambda line: len(line) >1 )
    .map(extract)) # Map to tuples

 row = Row("val") 
 df = Data.map(row).toDF()
 df.map(lambda r: r.x).stdev()
```

When I run this I get error as: `AttributeError: x` at `df.map(lambda r: r.x).stdev()`. **NOTE:** Some of values in my data are negative

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Spark < 1.6.0 you have a few options:

- convert to RDD and use `stdev` method:

  ```
  from pyspark.sql import Row
  import numpy as np

  row = Row("x")

  df = sc.parallelize([row(float(x)) for x in np.random.randn(100)]).toDF()
  df.rdd.map(lambda r: r.x).stdev()
  ```
- use following formula ([here is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31791275/1560062) a Scala version):

  [image]

  ```
  from pyspark.sql.functions import avg, pow, col, sqrt, lit

  sd = sqrt(
     avg(col("x") * col("x")) - pow(avg(col("x")), lit(2))).alias("stdev")

  df.select(sd)
  ```
- Hive UDF:

  ```
  df.registerTempTable("df")

  sqlContext.sql("SELECT stddev(x) AS sd FROM df")
  ```

Spark 1.6.0 introduces [`stddev`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/068b6438d6886ce5b4aa698383866f466d913d66/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py#L127), [`stddev_samp`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/068b6438d6886ce5b4aa698383866f466d913d66/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py#L129) and [`stddev_pop`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/068b6438d6886ce5b4aa698383866f466d913d66/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py#L131) functions.