# Spark Scala - How do I iterate rows in dataframe, and add calculated values as new columns of the data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with two columns "date" and "value", how do I add 2 new columns "value_mean" and "value_sd" to the dataframe where "value_mean" is the average of "value" over the last 10 days (including the current day as specified in "date") and "value_sd" is the standard deviation of the "value" over the last 10 days?

Comment: If data can be naturally partitioned by some (for example year or month) you can use a solution described in http://stackoverflow.com/q/33207164/1560062 Otherwise this problem is not a good fit for DataFrames.

Comment: Thanks! Average (mean) works beautifully over window partitions but not "stddev". Do you know how to do standard deviation on WindowSpec?

Comment: Build your own from basic expressions. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31791275/1560062

Answer (score 3):

Spark sql provide the [various dataframe function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html)  like avg,mean,sum etc.

you just have to apply on dataframe column using [spark sql column](http://org.apache.spark.sql.Column)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

Create private method for standard deviation

```
private def stddev(col: Column): Column = sqrt(avg(col * col) - avg(col) * avg(col))
```

Now you can create sql Column for average and standard deviation

```
val value_sd: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = stddev(df.col("value")).as("value_sd")
val value_mean: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = avg(df.col("value").as("value_mean"))
```

Filter your dataframe for last 10 days or as you want

```
val filterDF=df.filter("")//put your filter condition
```

Now yon can apply the aggregate function on your filterDF

```
filterDF.agg(stdv, value_mean).show
```