# Spark Build Custom Column Function, user defined function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I’m using Scala and want to build my own DataFrame function.  For example, I want to treat a column like an array , iterate through each element and make a calculation.

To start off, I’m trying to implement my own getMax method. So column x would have the values [3,8,2,5,9], and the expected output of the method would be 9.

Here is what it looks like in Scala

```
def getMax(inputArray: Array[Int]): Int = {
   var maxValue = inputArray(0)
   for (i <- 1 until inputArray.length if inputArray(i) > maxValue) {
     maxValue = inputArray(i)
   }
   maxValue
}
```

This is what I have so far, and get this error

```
"value length is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.column",
```

and I don't know how else to iterate through the column.

```
def getMax(col: Column): Column = {
var maxValue = col(0)
for (i <- 1 until col.length if col(i) > maxValue){
    maxValue = col(i)
}
maxValue
```

}

Once I am able to implement my own method, I will create a column function

```
val value_max:org.apache.spark.sql.Column=getMax(df.col(“value”)).as(“value_max”)
```

And then I hope to be able to use this in a SQL statement, for example

```
val sample = sqlContext.sql("SELECT value_max(x) FROM table")
```

and the expected output would be 9, given input column [3,8,2,5,9]

I am following an answer from another thread [Spark Scala - How do I iterate rows in dataframe, and add calculated values as new columns of the data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35348519/spark-scala-how-do-i-iterate-rows-in-dataframe-and-add-calculated-values-as-n) where they create a private method for standard deviation. 
The calculations I will do will be more complex than this, (e.g I will be comparing each element in the column) , am I going in the correct directions or should I be looking more into User Defined Functions?

Comment: Please show your input and output/expected dataframes. Use `show`.

Comment: Hi @JacekLaskowski thanks for the comment, I've edited the question to make it clearer what I would like to achieve.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In a Spark DataFrame, you can't iterate through the elements of a Column using the approaches you thought of because a Column is not an iterable object.

However, to  process the values of a column, you have some options and the right one depends on your task:

**1) Using the existing built-in functions**

Spark SQL already has plenty of useful functions for processing columns, including aggregation and transformation functions. Most of them you can find in the `functions` package ([documentation here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$)). Some others (binary functions in general) you can find directly in the `Column` object ([documentation here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column)). So, if you can use them, it's usually the best option. **Note:** don't forget the [Window Functions](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html).

**2) Creating an UDF**

If you can't complete your task with the built-in functions, you may consider defining an UDF (User Defined Function). They are useful when you can process each item of a column independently and you expect to produce a new column with the same number of rows as the original one (not an aggregated column). This approach is quite simple: first, you define a simple function, then you register it as an UDF, then you use it. Example:

```scala
def myFunc: (String => String) = { s => s.toLowerCase }

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val myUDF = udf(myFunc)

val newDF = df.withColumn("newCol", myUDF(df("oldCol")))
```

For more information, [here's](http://www.sparktutorials.net/using-sparksql-udfs-to-create-date-times-in-spark-1.5) a nice article.

**3) Using an UDAF**

If your task is to create aggregated data, you can define an UDAF (User Defined Aggregation Function). I don't have a lot of experience with this, but I can point you to a nice tutorial:

https://ragrawal.wordpress.com/2015/11/03/spark-custom-udaf-example/

**4) Fall back to RDD processing**

If you really can't use the options above, or if you processing task depends on different rows for processing one and it's not an aggregation, then I think you would have to select the column you want and process it using the corresponding RDD. Example:

```
val singleColumnDF = df("column")

val myRDD = singleColumnDF.rdd

// process myRDD
```

---

So, there was the options I could think of. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, very informative. So the main difference between UDF and UDAF is that a UDAF returns one value based on column calculation? I am hoping that the built in functions will be sufficient for what I want to do, but it would be good to know how to implement my own functions.

Comment: @other15 An UDAF is usually applied with `groupBy`, so it can return an aggregated value for each distinct value in the columns passed to `groupBy` (similar to how a simple `df.groupBy("key").agg(avg("value"))` works). However, if you don't use groupBy, the UDAF will return only one value.

Answer (score 4):

An easy example is given in the [excellent documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$), where a whole section is dedicated to UDFs:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._

val df = Seq(("id1", 1), ("id2", 4), ("id3", 5)).toDF("id", "value")
val spark = df.sparkSession
spark.udf.register("simpleUDF", (v: Int) => v * v)
df.select($"id", callUDF("simpleUDF", $"value"))
```

Comment: The link http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$ redirects to the http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#package . Couldn't you fix it?