# TypeError: Column is not iterable - How to iterate over ArrayType()?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Consider the following DataFrame:

```
+------+-----------------------+
|type  |names                  |
+------+-----------------------+
|person|[john, sam, jane]      |
|pet   |[whiskers, rover, fido]|
+------+-----------------------+
```

Which can be created with the following code:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
data = [
    ('person', ['john', 'sam', 'jane']),
    ('pet', ['whiskers', 'rover', 'fido'])
]

df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(data, ["type", "names"])
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Is there a way to directly modify the `ArrayType()` column `"names"` by applying a function to each element, without using a `udf`?

For example, suppose I wanted to apply the function `foo` to the `"names"` column. (I will use the example where `foo` is `str.upper` just for illustrative purposes, but my question is regarding any valid function that can be applied to the elements of an iterable.)

```python
foo = lambda x: x.upper()  # defining it as str.upper as an example
df.withColumn('X', [foo(x) for x in f.col("names")]).show()
```

> TypeError: Column is not iterable

I could do this using a `udf`:

```python
foo_udf = f.udf(lambda row: [foo(x) for x in row], ArrayType(StringType()))
df.withColumn('names', foo_udf(f.col('names'))).show(truncate=False)
#+------+-----------------------+
#|type  |names                  |
#+------+-----------------------+
#|person|[JOHN, SAM, JANE]      |
#|pet   |[WHISKERS, ROVER, FIDO]|
#+------+-----------------------+
```

In this specific example, I *could* avoid the `udf` by exploding the column, call `pyspark.sql.functions.upper()`, and then `groupBy` and `collect_list`:

```python
df.select('type', f.explode('names').alias('name'))\
    .withColumn('name', f.upper(f.col('name')))\
    .groupBy('type')\
    .agg(f.collect_list('name').alias('names'))\
    .show(truncate=False)
#+------+-----------------------+
#|type  |names                  |
#+------+-----------------------+
#|person|[JOHN, SAM, JANE]      |
#|pet   |[WHISKERS, ROVER, FIDO]|
#+------+-----------------------+
```

But this is a lot of code to do something simple. Is there is a more direct way to iterate over the elements of an `ArrayType()` using spark-dataframe functions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In **Spark < 2.4** you can use an user defined function:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, DataType, StringType

def transform(f, t=StringType()):
    if not isinstance(t, DataType):
       raise TypeError("Invalid type {}".format(type(t)))
    @udf(ArrayType(t))
    def _(xs):
        if xs is not None:
            return [f(x) for x in xs]
    return _

foo_udf = transform(str.upper)

df.withColumn('names', foo_udf(f.col('names'))).show(truncate=False)
```

```
+------+-----------------------+
|type  |names                  |
+------+-----------------------+
|person|[JOHN, SAM, JANE]      |
|pet   |[WHISKERS, ROVER, FIDO]|
+------+-----------------------+
```

Considering high cost of [`explode`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode) + [`collect_list`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list) idiom, this approach is almost exclusively preferred, despite its intrinsic cost.

In **Spark 2.4** or later you can use [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform)* with [`upper`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#upper) (see [SPARK-23909](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23909)):

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df.withColumn(
    'names', expr('transform(names, x -> upper(x))')
).show(truncate=False)
```

```
+------+-----------------------+
|type  |names                  |
+------+-----------------------+
|person|[JOHN, SAM, JANE]      |
|pet   |[WHISKERS, ROVER, FIDO]|
+------+-----------------------+
```

It is also possible to use `pandas_udf`

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

def transform_pandas(f, t=StringType()):
    if not isinstance(t, DataType):
       raise TypeError("Invalid type {}".format(type(t)))
    @pandas_udf(ArrayType(t), PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
    def _(xs):
        return xs.apply(lambda xs: [f(x) for x in xs] if xs is not None else xs)
    return _

foo_udf_pandas = transform_pandas(str.upper)

df.withColumn('names', foo_udf(f.col('names'))).show(truncate=False)
```

```
+------+-----------------------+
|type  |names                  |
+------+-----------------------+
|person|[JOHN, SAM, JANE]      |
|pet   |[WHISKERS, ROVER, FIDO]|
+------+-----------------------+
```

although only the latest Arrow / PySpark combinations support handling `ArrayType` columns ([SPARK-24259](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24259), [SPARK-21187](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21187)). Nonetheless this option should be more efficient than standard UDF (especially with a lower serde overhead) while supporting arbitrary Python functions.

---

* [A number of other higher order functions are also supported](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html), including, but not limited to [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#filter) and [`aggregate`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#aggregate). See for example

- [Querying Spark SQL DataFrame with complex types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28332494/10465355)
- [How to slice and sum elements of array column?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40151064/10465355)
- [Filter array column content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53193144/10465355)
- [Spark Scala row-wise average by handling null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53189965/10465355).
- [How to use transform higher-order function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53761600/10465355).

Comment: @pault Thanks for the edit. [Spark's own SQL docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform) could be a better target (although there are not grouped by category) - what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it by converting it to RDD and then back to DF.

```
>>> df.show(truncate=False)
+------+-----------------------+
|type  |names                  |
+------+-----------------------+
|person|[john, sam, jane]      |
|pet   |[whiskers, rover, fido]|
+------+-----------------------+

>>> df.rdd.mapValues(lambda x: [y.upper() for y in x]).toDF(["type","names"]).show(truncate=False)
+------+-----------------------+
|type  |names                  |
+------+-----------------------+
|person|[JOHN, SAM, JANE]      |
|pet   |[WHISKERS, ROVER, FIDO]|
+------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am aware of this method as well, but I was looking for something using only spark-dataframe syntax. Do you know how serialization to rdd and back compares with using a udf? My understanding is that using the udf is preferred, but I have no documentation to back that up.

Comment: As for as I am aware, Spark is unable to manage memory of a worker once the data enters Python. Both JVM & Python competes for memory on a single machine creating resource contraints which may cause a worker to fail.