# Replace spaces with underscores inside array elements in PySpark

Tags: arrays, regex, pyspark

I have a Spark dataframe:

| id | objects |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [sun, solar system, mars, milky way] |
| 2 | [moon, cosmic rays, orion nebula] |

I need to replace space with underscore in array elements.

Expected result:

| id | objects | concat_obj |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [sun, solar system, mars, milky way] | [sun, solar_system, mars, milky_way] |
| 2 | [moon, cosmic rays, orion nebula] | [moon, cosmic_rays, orion_nebula] |

I tried using `regexp_replace`:

```
df = df.withColumn('concat_obj', regexp_replace('objects', ' ', '_'))
```

but that changed **all** spaces to underscores while I need to replace spaces only inside array elements.
So, how can this be done in PySpark?

Comment: See if this helps: [transform] (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform.html)
and on the similar lines https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51706383/pyspark-removing-special-numeric-strings-from-array-of-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use highe order functions to replace white space through regexp_replace

schema

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- objects: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

solution

```
df.withColumn('concat_obj', expr("transform(objects, x-> regexp_replace(x,' ','_'))")).show(truncate=False)

+---+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|id |objects                             |concat_obj                          |
+---+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|1  |[sun, solar system, mars, milky way]|[sun, solar_system, mars, milky_way]|
|2  |[moon, cosmic rays, orion nebula]   |[moon, cosmic_rays, orion_nebula]   |
+---+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following regex:

```
`(?<=[A-Za-z]) `
```

The only difference with respect to your code is that this pattern checks whether before the space there is an alphabetical character.

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/yDfQs8/1).

Comment: I got the following error: `ERROR CodeGenerator: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 246, Column 1: Assignment conversion not possible from type "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.ArrayData" to type "org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String"`

Comment: If you can provide a debugging environment with your code, I may help you further. I have no possibility of playing with pyspark at the moment. @red_quark

Comment: At the moment, I solved the problem in a different way by converting the array to a string and applying `regexp_replace`. But for the future, I'm still interested how to get the desired result without pre-converting the array to a string..