# Filter array column content

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using pyspark 2.3.1 and would like to filter array elements with an expression and not an using udf:

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "A", [1,2,3,4]), (2, "B", [1,2,3,4,5])],["col1", "col2", "col3"])
>>> df.show()
+----+----+---------------+
|col1|col2|           col3|
+----+----+---------------+
|   1|   A|   [1, 2, 3, 4]|
|   2|   B|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|
+----+----+---------------+
```

The expreesion shown below is wrong, I wonder how to tell spark to remove out any values from the array in col3 which are smaller than 3. I want something like:

```
>>> filtered = df.withColumn("newcol", expr("filter(col3, x -> x >= 3)")).show()
>>> filtered.show()
+----+----+---------+
|col1|col2|   newcol|
+----+----+---------+
|   1|   A|   [3, 4]|
|   2|   B|[3, 4, 5]|
+----+----+---------+
```

I have already an udf solution, but it is very slow (> 1 billions data rows):

```
largerThan = F.udf(lambda row,max: [x for x in row if x >= max], ArrayType(IntegerType()))
df = df.withColumn('newcol', size(largerThan(df.queries, lit(3))))
```

Any help is welcome. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You can't iterate over an array. You can `explode`, `filter`, and `collect_list` to avoid the `udf`, but this is also an expensive operation. You can also serialize to `rdd`. See [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993439/typeerror-column-is-not-iterable-how-to-iterate-over-arraytype)

Answer (score 11):

**Spark < 2.4**

There is no *reasonable replacement for `udf` in PySpark.

**Spark >= 2.4**

Your code:

```
expr("filter(col3, x -> x >= 3)")
```

can be used as is.

**Reference**

[Querying Spark SQL DataFrame with complex types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28332494)

---

* Given the cost of exploding or converting to and from RDD `udf` is almost exclusively preferable.