# Filter an array in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Spark version: 2.3.0

I have a PySpark dataframe that has an Array column, and I want to filter the array elements by applying some string matching conditions. Eg: If I had a dataframe like this

```
       Array Col
['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
['strawberry', 'raspberry']
['apple', 'pineapple', 'grapes']
```

I would want to filter the elements within each array that contain the string 'apple' or, start with 'app' etc. How would I achieve this in PySpark?

Could someone tell me how I can implement it in pyspark?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter array column content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53193144/filter-array-column-content)

Comment: Nope. That answer is only for spark version > 2.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter.html?highlight=filter#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter) in conjunction with [exist](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.exists.html?highlight=exists) which comes under Higher Order [Functions](https://towardsdatascience.com/higher-order-functions-with-spark-3-1-7c6cf591beaa) that will check if any of the elements within the array contains the `word`

The other approach would be a UDF -

#### Data Preparation

```
sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame([(['apple', 'banana', 'orange'],),
                               (['strawberry', 'raspberry'],),
                               (['apple', 'pineapple', 'grapes'],)
                              ]
                              ,['arr_column']
                             )


sparkDF.show(truncate=False)

+--------------------------+
|arr_column                |
+--------------------------+
|[apple, banana, orange]   |
|[strawberry, raspberry]   |
|[apple, pineapple, grapes]|
+--------------------------+
```

#### Filter & Exists >= Spark 2.4

```
starts_with_app = lambda s: s.startswith("app")

sparkDF_filtered = sparkDF.filter(F.exists(F.col("arr_column"), starts_with_app))

sparkDF_filtered.show(truncate=False)

+--------------------------+
|arr_column                |
+--------------------------+
|[apple, banana, orange]   |
|[apple, pineapple, grapes]|
+--------------------------+
```

#### UDF - Lower Versions as well

```
def filter_string(inp):
    
    res = []
    
    for s in inp:
        if s.startswith("app"):
            res += [s]
    if res:
        return res
    else:
        return None

filter_string_udf = F.udf(lambda x: filter_string(x),ArrayType(StringType()))

sparkDF_filtered = sparkDF.withColumn('arr_filtered',filter_string_udf(F.col('arr_column')))\
                          .filter(F.col('arr_filtered').isNotNull())

sparkDF_filtered.show(truncate=False)

+--------------------------+------------+
|arr_column                |arr_filtered|
+--------------------------+------------+
|[apple, banana, orange]   |[apple]     |
|[apple, pineapple, grapes]|[apple]     |
+--------------------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use higher order functions from spark 2.4+:

```
df.withColumn("Filtered_Col",F.expr(f"filter(Array_Col,x -> x rlike '^(?i)app' )")).show()
```

---

```
+--------------------------+------------+
|Array_Col                 |Filtered_Col|
+--------------------------+------------+
|[apple, banana, orange]   |[apple]     |
|[strawberry, raspberry]   |[]          |
|[apple, pineapple, grapes]|[apple]     |
+--------------------------+------------+
```

For lower versions, you are probably good to use an udf:

```
import re
def myf(v):
  l=[]
  for i in v:
    if bool(re.match('^(?i)app',i)):
      l.append(i)
  return l
myudf = F.udf(myf,T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))
df.withColumn("Filtered_Col",myudf("Array_Col")).show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, unfortunately, I can only use spark 2.3.0 in my organization. :( Do you have an alternate solution for that? I'll edit my question to mention the same

Comment: @AnonymousMe updated with another alternative for lower versions. both with match both `Apple` and `apple`, remove the `(?i)` if you dont want to match the capital `A`

Comment: @AnonymousMe Also, looks like you want to also filter out rows with 0 matches? its not addressed in OP , however you can chain a `.where` with `size` check: `df.withColumn("Filtered_Col",myudf("Array_Col")).where(F.size("Filtered_Col")>0).show()
`