# filter pyspark Array column based on regex gives incorrect filtering

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

cSchema = StructType([StructField("WordList", ArrayType(StringType()))])

# notice extra square brackets around each element of list 
test_list = [['share_db.sc.tbl']], [['x a','d.s.t','d.s']]

df = spark.createDataFrame(test_list,schema=cSchema)

# check regex works to filter list element

df.withColumn("Filtered_Col", expr(f"filter(WordList,x -> x rlike '^(?i)share' )")).show()

#wrong output
df.withColumn(
    "filtered_query_text_split",
    expr('filter(WordList, x -> x rlike "([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\\.([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\\.([a-zA-Z0-9]*)" )')
).show()

#check wrong's regex is ok by splitting
dSchema = StructType([StructField("Words", StringType())\
                      ,StructField("total", IntegerType())])

test_list = [['Hello to you', 1], ['x.y.z', 3]]

df_two = spark.createDataFrame(test_list,schema=dSchema)

df_two.filter(col("Words").rlike("([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\\.([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\\.([a-zA-Z0-9]*)")).show()
```

```
df.withColumn(
    "filtered_query_text_split",
    expr('filter(WordList, x -> x rlike "([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\\.([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\\.([a-zA-Z0-9]*)" )')
).show()
```

i expected it to filter in only d.s.t & share_db.sc.tbl.

The same regex worked if the strings were individual rows.

I'm following this SO [Filter an array in pyspark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69406983/filter-an-array-in-pyspark-dataframe)

JFYI i'm on glue 2 / spark 2.4

Comment: Try changing `*` with `*?`.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/11899084/2956135

Comment: no change @Emma

Comment: how about `+?` instead of `*?`?

Comment: hot damn, that worked. No idea why. Thanks! @Emma