# How to use transform higher-order function?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

It's about `transform` higher-order function (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23908).

Is there any way to use it as a standard function (in package `org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`)?

I have an array of strings and I want to apply URI normalization to each of them. For now I did it with an UDF. I just hopped that with spark 2.4.0 I would be able to skip the UDF.

As I see it should be used in `selectExpr` like `df.selectExpr("transform(i, x -> x + 1)")` but is it only meant to be used with `selectExpr`?

Using it this way is there anyway to provide a custom function for the transformation? Is there any way to achieve it or should I resort to using good old UDFs?

Comment: Can you describe your use case? I think using UDFs is the fastest performance-wise.

Comment: I have an array of strings and I want to apply URI normalization to each of them. For now I did it with an UDF. I just hopped that with spark 2.4.0 I would be able to skip the UDF.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there anyway to use it as a standard function located in package org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ ?

For now it is intended only for usage with SQL expressions, although if you want to return a `Column` your use `expr`:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

expr("transform(i, x -> x + 1)"): Column
```

> Using it this way is there anyway to provide a custom function for the transformation?

It is possible to use Scala UDF*:

```scala
spark.udf.register("f", (x: Int) => x + 1)

Seq((1, Seq(1, 2, 3))).toDF("id", "xs")
  .withColumn("xsinc", expr("transform(xs, x -> f(x))"))
  .show
```

```scala
+---+---------+---------+
| id|       xs|    xsinc|
+---+---------+---------+
|  1|[1, 2, 3]|[2, 3, 4]|
+---+---------+---------+
```

although it doesn't seem to provide any real benefits over UDF taking a `Seq`.

---

* A partial support for Python UDFs seem to be in place (udfs are recognized, types are correctly derived, and calls are dispatched) as well, but as of 2.4.0 the serialization mechanism seems to be broken (all records are passed to UDF as `None`):

```
from typing import Optional
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

sc.version
```

```
'2.4.0'
```

```py
def f(x: Optional[int]) -> Optional[int]:
    return x + 1 if x is not None else None

spark.udf.register('f', f, "integer")

df = (spark
    .createDataFrame([(1, [1, 2, 3])], ("id", "xs"))
    .withColumn("xsinc", expr("transform(xs, x -> f(x))")))

df.printSchema()
```

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- xs: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |-- xsinc: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

```py
df.show()
```

```
+---+---------+-----+
| id|       xs|xsinc|
+---+---------+-----+
|  1|[1, 2, 3]| [,,]|
+---+---------+-----+
```

Of course there is no real potential for performance boost here - it dispatches to `BasePythonRunner` so overhead should be the same as of plain `udf`.

Related JIRA ticket [SPARK-27052 - Using PySpark udf in transform yields NULL values](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27052)

Comment: the fact you said if you want a hof to return a column use F.expr() makes me think in SQL you can use them to do more than just work on a single column. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in python, as reported in the answer above, there is a problem with the expr function using a udf, but it can be done as follows:

```
from typing import Optional
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr, transform

def f(x: Optional[int]) -> Optional[int]:
    return x + 1 if x is not None else None

spark.udf.register('f', f, "integer")

df = (spark
    .createDataFrame(
        [(1, [1, 2, 3])], ("id", "xs"))
    .withColumn("xsinc", eval("transform(col('xs'),  lambda x: f(x))")))

df.show()
```

```
+---+---------+---------+
| id|       xs|    xsinc|
+---+---------+---------+
|  1|[1, 2, 3]|[2, 3, 4]|
+---+---------+---------+
```