# Exploding and Splitting columns causing data mismatch

Tags: python, arrays, pyspark

I have a dataset that provides me what people have watched on TV, the duration they have watched and on which network they have watched. We have following columns:

```
TV ID - string
show_nw - Array which has TV show concatenated with Network
All_nws - Array which has network concatenated with Duration
All_shows - Array which has show concatenated with duration
```

Sample dataset:

```
 TV_ID : a1001 , a1002, a1003
 show_nw:  ["TheFactsofLife#1001","Bewitched#1001","Survivor#1000","SEALTeam#1000","WhenWhalesWalkedJourneysinDeepTime#1002","PaidProgramming#1006"], ["AllEliteWrestlingDynamite#1003","TheAdjustmentBureau#1004","Charmed#1003"], ["TMJ4Now#1005"]
 all_nws  : ["1000#7062","1001#602","1002#40","1006#47"], ["1003#7328","1004#46"], ["1005#1543"]
 all_shows : ["Bewitched#563","Survivor#6988","SEALTeam#74","WhenWhalesWalkedJourneysinDeepTime#40","PaidProgramming#47","TheFactsofLife#39"], ["Charmed#462","AllEliteWrestlingDynamite#6866","TheAdjustmentBureau#46"], ["TMJ4Now#1543"]
```

Now when I am exploding the dataset back from array

```
test_df = df.select("tv_id", "all_shows", "all_nws").withColumn("all_shows", explode("all_shows")).withColumn("all_nws", explode("all_nws")).withColumn("show",split(col("all_shows"),"#").getItem(0)).withColumn("network",split(col("all_nws"),"#").getItem(0))
```

My output looks like:

```
tv_id    all_shows            all_nws          show           network
a1001    Bewitched#563        1000#7062        Bewitched      1000
a1001    Bewitched#563        1001#602         Bewitched      1001
a1001    Bewitched#563        1002#40          Bewitched      1002
a1001    Bewitched#563        1006#47          Bewitched      1006
a1001    Survivor#6988        1000#7062        Survivor       1000
a1001    Survivor#6988        1001#602         Survivor       1001
a1001    Survivor#6988        1002#40          Survivor       1002
a1001    Survivor#6988        1006#47          Survivor       1006
```

So basically in the parent dataset, Bewitched and Survivor were watched only on network 1000 but when exploded, we found both of them were associated with all the networks that TV_ID had. How do I get the correct dataset after the explosion in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to do **`zip arrays`** before exploding.

- From **`Spark-2.4`** use `arrays_zip` function.
- For **`Spark < 2.4`** need to use [udf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54282706/how-to-zip-two-array-columns-in-spark-sql/54288690).

**`Example:(Spark-2.4)`**

```
#sample dataframe.
df.show()
#+-----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
#|tv_id|             show_nw|             all_nws|           all_shows|
#+-----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
#|a1001|[TheFactsofLife#1...|[1000#7062, 1001#...|[Bewitched#563, S...|
#|a1002|[AllEliteWrestlin...|[1003#7328, 1004#46]|[Charmed#462, All...|
#|a1003|      [TMJ4Now#1005]|         [1005#1543]|      [TMJ4Now#1543]|
#+-----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+

df.select("tv_id", "all_shows", "all_nws").\
withColumn("all_shows", explode(arrays_zip("all_shows","all_nws"))).\
select("tv_id","all_shows.*").\
withColumn("show",split(col("all_shows"),"#").getItem(0)).\
withColumn("network",split(col("all_nws"),"#").getItem(0)).\
show()
#+-----+--------------------+---------+--------------------+-------+
#|tv_id|           all_shows|  all_nws|                show|network|
#+-----+--------------------+---------+--------------------+-------+
#|a1001|       Bewitched#563|1000#7062|           Bewitched|   1000|
#|a1001|       Survivor#6988| 1001#602|            Survivor|   1001|
#|a1001|         SEALTeam#74|  1002#40|            SEALTeam|   1002|
#|a1001|WhenWhalesWalkedJ...|  1006#47|WhenWhalesWalkedJ...|   1006|
#|a1001|  PaidProgramming#47|     null|     PaidProgramming|   null|
#|a1001|   TheFactsofLife#39|     null|      TheFactsofLife|   null|
#|a1002|         Charmed#462|1003#7328|             Charmed|   1003|
#|a1002|AllEliteWrestling...|  1004#46|AllEliteWrestling...|   1004|
#|a1002|TheAdjustmentBure...|     null| TheAdjustmentBureau|   null|
#|a1003|        TMJ4Now#1543|1005#1543|             TMJ4Now|   1005|
#+-----+--------------------+---------+--------------------+-------+
```

Comment: Thats great. But one thing i am seeing in ur output is that some are coming as null in network

Comment: @BitanshuDas, We are zipping two arrays and `all_shows` column has 6 elements in array and `all_nws ` have 4 elements in array so last ** two elements** doesn't have zip in `all_nws` column this results null in network!