# Error when passing Spark SQL higher order functions lambda variable to custom SQL user defined function (UDF)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have created a SQL UDF which takes one string parameter and returns string.

Reference doc : https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-sql-function.html#parameters

I am trying to use this function inside Spark SQL's array_transform method.

SQL UDF function DDL

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION printStr(str String )
  RETURNS STRING
  COMMENT 'print given string'
  LANGUAGE SQL
  RETURN str
```

Temp view to test SQL UDF

```
CREATE or REPLACE TEMP VIEW values AS 
select * from values (array("1","2","3")),(array("2","3","5")),(array("3","44"))
```

Calling this SQL UDF inside Spark SQL's [array_transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#transform) method.

`select transform(col1, val -> printStr(val)) from VALUES`

Exception: (Spark version - 3.2.1, Scala - 2.12, Databricks runtime - 10.4 LTS)

```
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) val#1298163 missing from  in operator !Project [cast(lambda val#1298163 as string) AS str#1298165].; line 1 pos 30

com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.DatabricksExceptions$SQLExecutionException: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) val#1298163 missing from  in operator !Project [cast(lambda val#1298163 as string) AS str#1298165].; line 1 pos 30
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.failAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.failAnalysis$(CheckAnalysis.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.failAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis$2(CheckAnalysis.scala:533)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis$2$adapted(CheckAnalysis.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$foreachUp$1(TreeNode.scala:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$foreachUp$1$adapted(TreeNode.scala:357)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1(CheckAnalysis.scala:105)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:100)
```

Am guessing namedLambdaVariable is not getting resolved inside SQL UDf's

Comment: If it's any consolation, I have the same problem too. Someone else apparently did also https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/udf-not-working-inside-transform-amp-lambda-sql/td-p/35762 but no one answered their question on the Databricks community forum either. (Web archive version of link: https://web.archive.org/web/20230825113110/https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/udf-not-working-inside-transform-amp-lambda-sql/td-p/35762 )  Apparently Python UDFs aren't supported either (not just SQL UDFs, like this question) https://stackoverflow.com/a/53762650/10634604