# Modify all elements in ArrayType

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame with a column of `ArrayType(StringType)`:

```
+------------------------------------+
|colname                             |
+------------------------------------+
|[foo_XX_foo, bar_YY_bar]            |
|[qwe_ZZ_rty, asd_AA_fgh, zxc_BB_vbn]|
+------------------------------------+
```

I would now like to extract the string between the first and the second `_`, i.e. expected output is:

```
+------------+
|newcolname  |
+------------+
|[XX, YY]    |
|[ZZ, AA, BB]|
+------------+
```

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53486896/1945981), I tried to use `expr()` with `transform`, but I didn't manage to get it working. Even the example of altering all strings to uppercase, as in the above quoted answer, does not work for me, I get the following error:

> pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: u"\nextraneous input '>' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', ...

How can I modify all elements in an `ArrayType`? I would like to avoid using an `udf`.

Comment: What version of Spark are you using?

Comment: @Bala Spark 2.3.2

Comment: @pfnuesel `transform` is only available in 2.4+. Your best option is probably a `udf`, although there's a hacky way using `concat_ws`, `regexp_extract`, and `split`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little bit unsafe but try something like this:

```py
df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
  [["foo_XX_foo", "bar_YY_bar"]],
  [["qwe_ZZ_rty", "asd_AA_fgh", "zxc_BB_vbn"]]
]).toDF(['colname'])

df.selectExpr('transform(colname, x -> split(x, "_")[1]) as newcolname').show()
```

which results in:

```
+------------+
|  newcolname|
+------------+
|    [XX, YY]|
|[ZZ, AA, BB]|
+------------+
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using Spark version 2.3.2, [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform) is not available to you. Thus as explained in the [post you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993439/typeerror-column-is-not-iterable-how-to-iterate-over-arraytype), the best approach in general is to use `udf`.

However, in this specific case you may be able to avoid a `udf` using some hacky regular expression replacements.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat_ws, regexp_replace, split, trim

df.withColumn(
    "newcolname",
    regexp_replace(concat_ws(",", col("colname")), "((?<=_)[^_,]+(?=_))", " $1 ")
).withColumn(
    "newcolname",
    regexp_replace(col("newcolname"), "(_[^_ ]+_)", "")
).withColumn(
    "newcolname",
    regexp_replace(col("newcolname"), "([^_ ]+_)", "")
).withColumn(
    "newcolname",
    regexp_replace(col("newcolname"), "_([^_ ]+)", "")
).withColumn(
    "newcolname",
    split(trim(col("newcolname")), "\s+")
).show(truncate=False)
#+------------------------------------+------------+
#|colname                             |newcolname  |
#+------------------------------------+------------+
#|[foo_XX_foo, bar_YY_bar]            |[XX, YY]    |
#|[qwe_ZZ_rty, asd_AA_fgh, zxc_BB_vbn]|[ZZ, AA, BB]|
#+------------------------------------+------------+
```

---

### Explanation

First we take the `ArrayType(StringType())` column and concatenate the elements together to form one string. I used the comma as the separator, which only works if the comma does not appear in your data.

Next we perform a series of `regexp_replace` calls.

The first pattern `((?<=_)[^_,]+(?=_))` identifies the content that you actually want to extract: the text bracketed by the underscore. Then the matching groups are replaced the match group surrounded by spaces `" $1 "`. As before with the comma separator, this assumes that spaces do not appear in your data.

For example:

```
df.select(
    regexp_replace(
        concat_ws(",", col("colname")), 
        "((?<=_)[^_,]+(?=_))", 
        " $1 "
    ).alias("pattern1")
).show(truncate=False)
#+--------------------------------------+
#|pattern1                              |
#+--------------------------------------+
#|foo_ XX _foo,bar_ YY _bar             |
#|qwe_ ZZ _rty,asd_ AA _fgh,zxc_ BB _vbn|
#+--------------------------------------+
```

The next 3 calls to `regexp_replace` selectively remove the parts of this string that are not desired.

Finally at the end, only the desired content remains. The string is trimmed to removed trailing/leading whitespace and split on whitespace to get the final result.