# How to iterate the column in dataframe which has datatype as list

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have this dataframe:

```
+----+----+---+
|NAME|RANK| ID|
+----+----+---+
|null|   1|100|
| abc|   5|100|
| cyz|   2|100|
+----+----+---+
```

I am trying access the column `name` so that I can get first non-null element but I am getting the error:

> TypeError: column is not iterable

Here is what I tried:

```
grouped_df = df1.groupby('ID').agg(collect_list('NAME').alias("name")).select("*")
    
+---+----------------+
| ID|            name|
+---+----------------+
|100|[null, abc, cyz]|
+---+----------------+ 

grouped_df.withColumn('temp',next(s for s in grouped_df["name"] if s))
```

I can access the item in list by using `getItem` method but I am trying to get it dynamically

```
grouped_df.select("*").withColumn('finalName',grouped_df["name"].getItem(1))
```

I want output like this

```
+---+----------------+
| ID|            name|
+---+----------------+
|100|             abc|
+---+----------------+
```

If anyone have anyone has any idea please let me know

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Column is not iterable - How to iterate over ArrayType()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993439/typeerror-column-is-not-iterable-how-to-iterate-over-arraytype)

Comment: there are at least two issues with your question: (1) null values are skipped in collect_list unless they are literal string 'null'. (2) the order of items in collect_list is nondeterministic, they might not shown in the same order as your original data after GroupBy and shuffling.

Comment: If you just want a non-null element, you just need ```df1.where(col('name').isNotNull).head```. If certain order is desired, you could sort the dataframe by that order.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to apply a Python for comprehension on a Column object (`grouped_df["name"]` returns Column not list).

Actually when you use `collect_list` function, Spark ignores the null values, so you don't need to fetch the first non-null value in the array, just select the first element:

```
grouped_df.withColumn('temp', col("name").getItem(0))
```

But a better way to do this is to groupBy and select the first value using [`first`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/#first) function:

```
grouped_df = df1.groupby('ID').agg(first(col('NAME'), ignorenulls=True).alias("name")).select("*")
```