# Pass dataframe column name as parameter to the function using scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

```
I have a function that adds 2 columns:

def sum_num (num1: Int, num2: Int): Int = {
    return num1 + num2
}
```

I have a dataframe df with below values

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|1   |2   |5   |
|7   |4   |4   |
+----+----+----+
```

I want to add a column and pass column names to the function but the below code is not working. It gives error found Column required is Int

```
val newdf = df.withColumn("sum_of_cols1", sum_num($col1, $ col2))
              .withColumn("sum_of_cols2", sum_num($col1, $ col3))
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37227528/2501279) help?

Comment: @GuruStron I had seen this but not sure how to create the udf using multiple columns. Also i had read that udf might have some performance implications and since I am doing the calculation on billion records trying to find other solutions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
import spark.implicits._

def sum_num (num1: Column, num2: Column): Column = {
  return num1 + num2
}

val newdf = df.withColumn("sum_of_cols1", sum_num($"col1", $"col2"))
  .withColumn("sum_of_cols2", sum_num($"col1", $"col3"))
```

You must operate over Spark SQL columns. You can do arithmetic operations with them. Take a look to the [operators](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html) that can be used

Comment: thanks for this. for function sum_num does the output need to be a column or can i out Int there since I need that value to do some other calculation

Comment: you can operate with column directly, using the available operators. Don´t worry about that, if you need other specific functions you could add an udf that takes as input a column too.