# Normalize values of multiple columns in Spark DataFrame, using only DataFrame API

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to normalize the values of multiple columns in a spark dataframe, by subtracting the mean and dividing by the stddev of each column. Here's the code I have so far:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import stddev_pop, avg

df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(A=1, B=6), Row(A=2, B=7), Row(A=3, B=8),
                            Row(A=4, B=9), Row(A=5, B=10)])

exprs = [x - (avg(x)) / stddev_pop(x) for x in df.columns]    
df.select(exprs).show()
```

Which gives me the result:

```
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
|(A - (avg(A) / stddev_pop(A)))|(B - (avg(B) / stddev_pop(B)))|
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
|                          null|                          null|
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Where I'm hoping for:

```
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
|(A - (avg(A) / stddev_pop(A)))|(B - (avg(B) / stddev_pop(B)))|
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
|                  -1.414213562|                  -1.414213562|
|                  -0.707106781|                  -0.707106781|
|                             0|                             0|
|                   0.707106781|                   0.707106781|
|                   1.414213562|                   1.414213562|
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

I believe I can do this with the [StandardScaler](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html#standardscaler) class from mllib, but I'd prefer to do this using only the dataframe API if possible - if only as a learning exercise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create z score in spark sql for each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36807937/how-to-create-z-score-in-spark-sql-for-each-group)

Comment: @LostInOverflow it's certainly close, but my use case required normalising multiple columns

Answer (score 6):

With thanks to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36807937/how-to-create-z-score-in-spark-sql-for-each-group), I came up with this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import stddev_pop, avg, broadcast

cols = df.columns    
stats = (df.groupBy().agg(
        *([stddev_pop(x).alias(x + '_stddev') for x in cols] + 
          [avg(x).alias(x + '_avg') for x in cols])))

df = df.join(broadcast(stats))

exprs = [(df[x] - df[x + '_avg']) / df[x + '_stddev'] for x in cols]
df.select(exprs).show()

+------------------------+------------------------+
|((A - A_avg) / A_stddev)|((B - B_avg) / B_stddev)|
+------------------------+------------------------+
|      -1.414213562373095|      -1.414213562373095|
|     -0.7071067811865475|     -0.7071067811865475|
|                     0.0|                     0.0|
|      0.7071067811865475|      0.7071067811865475|
|       1.414213562373095|       1.414213562373095|
+------------------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: Why I meet error `Join condition is missing or trivial.` in spark `2.3`