# PySpark divide column by its sum

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to divide columns in PySpark by their respective sums. My dataframe(using only one column here) looks like this:

```
event_rates = [[1,10.461016949152542], [2, 10.38953488372093], [3, 10.609418282548477]]
event_rates = spark.createDataFrame(event_rates, ['cluster_id','mean_encoded'])
event_rates.show()

+----------+------------------+
|cluster_id|      mean_encoded|
+----------+------------------+
|         1|10.461016949152542|
|         2| 10.38953488372093|
|         3|10.609418282548477|
+----------+------------------+
```

I tried two methods to do this but have failed in getting results

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum as spark_sum
cols = event_rates.columns[1:]
for each in cols:
    event_rates = event_rates.withColumn(each+"_scaled", event_rates[each]/spark_sum(event_rates[each]))
```

This gives me the following error

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: grouping expressions sequence is empty, and '`cluster_id`' is not an aggregate function. Wrap '((`mean_encoded` / sum(`mean_encoded`)) AS `mean_encoded_scaled`)' in windowing function(s) or wrap '`cluster_id`' in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;;
Aggregate [cluster_id#22356L, mean_encoded#22357, (mean_encoded#22357 / sum(mean_encoded#22357)) AS mean_encoded_scaled#2
```

and following the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993879/normalize-values-of-multiple-columns-in-spark-dataframe-using-only-dataframe-ap?rq=1) I tried the following

```
stats = (event_rates.agg([spark_sum(x).alias(x + '_sum') for x in cols]))
event_rates = event_rates.join(broadcast(stats))
exprs = [event_rates[x] / event_rates[event_rates + '_sum'] for x in cols]
event_rates.select(exprs)
```

But I get an error from the first line stating

```
AssertionError: all exprs should be Column
```

How do I get across this?

Answer (score 4):

This is an example on how to divide column `mean_encoded` by its sum. You need to sum the column first then `crossJoin` back to the previous dataframe. Then, you can divide any column by its sum.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn
from pyspark.sql.types import *

event_rates = event_rates.crossJoin(event_rates.groupby().agg(fn.sum('mean_encoded').alias('sum_mean_encoded')))
event_rates_div = event_rates.select('cluster_id', 
                                     'mean_encoded', 
                                     fn.col('mean_encoded') / fn.col('sum_mean_encoded'))
```

**Output**

```
+----------+------------------+---------------------------------+
|cluster_id|      mean_encoded|(mean_encoded / sum_mean_encoded)|
+----------+------------------+---------------------------------+
|         1|10.461016949152542|               0.3325183371367686|
|         2| 10.38953488372093|               0.3302461777809474|
|         3|10.609418282548477|               0.3372354850822839|
+----------+------------------+---------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this,

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
total = event_rates.groupBy().agg(F.sum("mean_encoded"),F.sum("cluster_id")).collect()
total
```

Answer will be,

> [Row(sum(mean_encoded)=31.459970115421946, sum(cluster_id)=6)]