# How to normalize vectors in spark using scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, statistics, normalization

I have 9 parquet files which contain 2 columns(id,features) and multiple rows.I want to calculate z-score value using (x - mean)/stddev).
dataset consists of 20 million record.
[each file look like image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kf7wD.jpg) 
My code

```
    val result1 = sorted.map(_.split(",")(0)).cache
    val count = result.count
    val mean = result.sum / count
    val devs = result.map(score => (score - mean) * (score - mean))
    val stddev = Math.sqrt(devs.sum / count)
    val zscore = sorted.map(x => math.round((x.toDouble - mean)/stddev))
```

How to calcaluate z-score for huge data?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a z-score in Spark SQL for each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36807937/how-to-create-a-z-score-in-spark-sql-for-each-group)

Comment: It's in python not scala.