# Calculate z-score in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to remove outliers using the modified z-score in pyspark. Here's the code that I have written:

```
def remove_outliers(df):
    df.sort(df.total_amount.asc()).show(truncate=False)
    median_amount = df.groupBy(df.total_amount).agg(
    pf.percentile_approx("total_amount", 0.5, pf.lit(1000000)).alias("median")
    )
    
    deviation_from_median = df.total_amount - median_amount  
    mad_amount = 1.483 * abs(percentile_approx(deviation_from_median_amount, 0.5, pf.lit(1000000)).alias("median"))
    zscore_amount = deviation_from_median_amount/mad_amount
    amount_outliers = (df.total_amount > zscore_amount)
    
    df = df.drop(amount_outliers)
    return df
```

Here's the dataset on which I am working:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/yellow_tripdata_2019-01.csv
```

And here's the error that I get after running the above function:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

Can you please guide me on what I am doing wrong here and is this the correct way to find the z-score in pyspark?

Comment: This is the best example for calculating Z-Score using Pyspark - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36807937/how-to-create-a-z-score-in-spark-sql-for-each-group

Comment: @Vaebhav That question does not help me, with my solution.