# computing Std deviation using RDD v/s SparkSQL in Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am pretty new to the world of spark ( and to an extend even Python , but better). I am trying to compute the standard deviation and had used the following code. The first using SparkSQL and the code is as follows:

```
 sqlsd=spark.sql("SELECT STDDEV(temperature) as stdtemp from 
 washing").first().stdtemp
 print(sqlsd)
```

The above works fine ( I think) and it gives the result as 6.070

Now when I try to do this using RDD with the following code:-

```
 def sdTemperature(df,spark):
    n=float(df.count())
    m=meanTemperature(df,spark) 
    df=df.fillna({'_id':0,'_rev':0,'count':0,'flowrate':0,'fluidlevel':0,
   'frequency':0,'hardness':0,'speed':0,'temperature':0,'ts':0,'voltage':0})
    rddT=df.rdd.map(lambda r: r.temperature)
    c=rddT.count()
    s=rddT.map(lambda x: pow(x-m,2)).sum()
    print(n,c,s)
    sd=sqrt(s/c)
    return sd
```

when I run the above code, I get a different result. the value I get is 53.195

what I am in doing wrong?. All I am trying to do above is to compute the std deviation for a spark dataframe column temperature and use lambda.

thanks in advance for help ..

Comment: Skipping `nulls` and filling them with `0` is not the same thing. Also there is a matter of numerical stability.

Comment: Thanks - i fully agree.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to Zero323 who gave me the clue. I skipped the null values . the modified code is as follows:-

```
 df2=df.na.drop(subset=["temperature"])
 rddT=df2.rdd.map(lambda r: r.temperature)
 c=rddT.count()
 s=rddT.map(lambda x: pow(x-m,2)).sum()
 sd=math.sqrt(s/c)
 return(sd)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of standard deviations - please refer to this : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15098/sample-standard-deviation-vs-population-standard-deviation

Similar question - 
[Calculate the standard deviation of grouped data in a Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31789939/calculate-the-standard-deviation-of-grouped-data-in-a-spark-dataframe)

The `stddev()` in Hive is a pointer to the `stddev_samp()`. The `stddev_pop()` is what you are looking for(inferred from the 2nd part of you code). So your sql query should be `select stddev_pop(temperature) as stdtemp from washing`

Comment: Thanks for your chipping in. But unfortunately that did not work. On changing std deviation from stdev tp stddev_pop still give the same result.